# Bindestrich bei Schrägstrich-Alternativen wiederholen?

Tags: typography, writing, hyphen

Schreibe ich „der VGA/DVI/HDMI-Kombiadapter“ oder „der VGA-/DVI-/HDMI-Kombiadapter“?

Es geht mir natürlich um die Bindestriche. Einer oder drei?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die Liste der Alternativen wird mit drei Bindestrichen geschrieben, also

> der VGA-/DVI-/HDMI-Kombiadapter

Der Bindestrich wird hierbei zusätzlich in seiner Funktion als Ergänzungsstrich verwendet. Der Ergänzungsstrich wird gesetzt, um anzuzeigen, dass ein gleicher Bestandteil von Zusammensetzungen oder Ableitungen eingespart wird. (Siehe hierzu zum Beispiel [Duden Regel 31](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich).)